# Sometimes, why is the response "gas" value from eth_estimateGas API lower than actual gas?

Tags: go-ethereum

- Sometimes, it responds to the difference "gas" value although the same input param

- Run "eth_estimateGas" API many times (about 15-25 calls) in the MainNet environment with params

  { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_estimateGas", "params": [ { "from": "0x9696f59e4d72e237be84ffd425dcad154bf96976", "to": "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7", "data": "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000000045a4c50c683aea78c0f02e05598ec3a4e0339cef0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046a1aa40" } ], "id": 1 }

- Returned gas

  - 0xb41d (= 46109) ==> Success when using this returned gas in Transaction
  - 0x94dd (= 38109) ==> Error "**out_of_gas**" occurs when using this returned gas in Transaction
- Try

  - TxHash: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x47a8baaa9512a5f8684e6d3c6fab35a823146ccb782349b01381615584e4828e
  - TxHash: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xcabbcf8d85a3125a67fc070890eed314554166e766ca5dc0926066f2c538ac84
  - TxHash: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf41301458f8701a0b0816d345a66cd81a3bace48a49da33705262e5f8e47550c

Comment: because gas usage depends on the execution path and the execution path is not static. It depends on the variables of the contract which are being changed by other traders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Because I do "transfer token" Transaction for USDT contract so gas value depends only on the state (Address's amount token > 0 or = 0) of Address's From or To in the storage contract. Therefore, I think "eth_estimateGas" should return at least 46109 but sometimes, it returns 38109 lower than 46109. At the time, "eth_estimateGas" returns 38109, it means that the "transfer" function (USDT contract) is successfully executed with that value (38109) but in fact, there is not existence a Transaction that successfully executes with that gas value (38109) => contradictory!!

Comment: there are lots of details that go under the hood. If you transfer all the balance of the token, the contract (I don't know if USDT does that or not) may delete the user's address from the contract storage. Therefore, there will be gas refund. But gas refunds are applied at the end of the transaction. So, eth_estimateGas may return less than you should really use, say transaction spend 12,000 gas, but refund was 3,000, so the estimate will be 9,000 but this is wrong because you need to use all 12,0000 in order to be able to finish the transaction.

Comment: another detail is: SafeMath has a `if (a==0) then return 0` https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code
This means that the following divide instructions will not be executed and less gas will be spent. You should view the contract source and account for every condition of the contract, only this way you can be certain that the gas usage will be the same as estimate

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The idea you suggested I have thought carefully. But still not solved the above problem